# Keep DIV scrolled to bottom when new content is added

Tags: javascript

I have a page that adds a new form to the bottom of a list of forms when the previous one was submitted and although I would like the page to scroll when it reaches a certain height so it scrolls to the top hiding the oldest form and revealing the new one at the bottom.

The new forms are creating using AJAX and that part works ok, it's just the scrolling bit I can't get working.

```
<div id="no_image_audit_wrapper" class="content_wrapper">
<ul id="responds">
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM add_delete_record";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
  <li id="item_<? echo $row['id'];?>">
  <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-<? echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />
  </a></div>
  <? echo $row["content"].' - '.$row["dropdown"].'</li>';
 }

?>
</ul>

    <div class="form_style">
    <form id="test_form">
    <select id="test" name="test">
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="FormSubmit" name="FormSubmit" id="FormSubmit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $cont = $('.content_wrapper');
    $cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;

    $('.FormSubmit').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keycode == 6){
        $cont.animate({ scrollTop: $cont[0].scrollHeight }, "slow");
        $(this).val('');
          }
     })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it by adding

```
$("#test_form").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

into the success function

```
success:function(response){
    $("#responds").append(response);
    $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#test_form").get(0).scrollIntoView();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to scroll to bottom. You can animate to scroll slowly

Javascript

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

JQuery

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's not the bottom of the page I want to scroll to but the bottom of the content_wrapper DIV

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Your_newly_added_form.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Or you can create a function like this

```
function scroll(elm){
elm.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

and call that function after the completion of ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, but my new form doesn't have a unique id so I can't see how I would implement that (I'm very new to Ajax and Javascript, learning as I go along)

Comment: Ok. So you have only form elements without any id ?

Comment: each time a new instance of the form is created it uses the same ID's as before for each element

Comment: So are you keeping the previous forms too ?

Comment: sorry, ignore what I said, I understand what you meant now.  I added $("#test_form").scrollIntoView(true); as the last statement in the success function but it still doesn't work

Comment: sussed it, I needed $("#test_form").get(0).scrollIntoView(); thanks for your help

Comment: I can't for 2 days, when the system lets me I'll come back and accept it